# GSAP callback functionality not working in Meteor

Tags: jquery, meteor, callback, gsap

I am stumped why i am unable to get a callback function to work especially when i have copied function straight from GSAP docs and it still does not work. I am beginning to think it is a Meteor issue with GSAP and its callback functions.
I don't have a problem with my animation just that it never runs the callback function and gives me a type error this.callback does not exist.

I want a callback cause i want to fade out the images when the animation is done and maybe run the function again or a different tween.

I am completely stumped so any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

here is my script:

```
  Template.home.rendered = function(){
    //var mainText = $('ul.images li').find('img').fadeIn('slow');
    TweenMax.staggerTo(".img", 1, {rotation:360, y:100, opacity: 1, onComplete:completeHandler, onCompleteParams:["animation complete!"]}, 0.5);
    function completeHandler(message) {
        console.log("onComplete fired completeParams = " + message);
    }
}
```

Here is my console output:

```
10TweenMax.min.js:14 Uncaught TypeError: this._callback is not a function
```

Comment: Do a codepen, and I'll take a look. :)

Comment: @DuncanTidd thank you, http://codepen.io/theller5567/pen/GZWdoq?editors=1011.

Comment: I was able to get the callback to work but now instead of only animating each icon when its done animating it animates all at once. When doing so you only get to see about half the images because their opacity is set to 0 before they even have  a chance to animate in. Hopefully that makes since, if not check the codepen link and you will see.